# Default button with JOptionsPane not working properly

Tags: java

I posted this code yesterday for another issue but now I once again must call on you all for help.. I appreciate all the assistance so far I have had without this community I wouldn't have made it so far.

Now, my problem is quite simple. I have a GUI with an input box for the user and three buttons. The buttons are not JButtons, they are the standard JOptionsPane yes, no, and cancel buttons. I did change the text to "next entry", "next batch", and "finished".

Before I made changes to my GUI I had standard buttons. The button that will most often be used is the "yes" button (now "next entry").. This button will be clicked a LOT in my program. Before the default button setting worked.. A user could simply type a number and press enter quickly. Now the enter key will not activate the default button instead the user must physically click on it.. This is what I want to change.

Is there any way I can set the below code so when the user clicks enter, regardless of what text they have typed, the "yes" (now "next batch" is clicked on default)? For what it's worth I did do research on this but could not find a solution that suited my specific circumstances.

```
package nacha;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Testing4 

{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String css = "<span style='font-size:10; color: white; background-color:black'>";
        String batchCss = "<span style='font-size: 20'>";
        String endSpanCss = "</span>"; 
        String table = "<table border=4>";
        String endTable = "</table>"; 
        String mainCss = "<span style='font-size:12; color: red'>";
        String header1Css = "<span style = 'font-size:15; font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;border:1px dotted red'>";
        String text1Css = "<span style = 'font-size:12; font-style:italic'>";



         String text = "<html>" +
                css + batchCss + "1 of 2"+endSpanCss+endSpanCss+ endSpanCss +
                "<br><br><br>"+header1Css+"Entry Detail:"+endSpanCss +
                "<br>"+mainCss+"111111111111111111111"+endSpanCss+
                "<br><br><br>"+text1Css+"Please type 1-21 to apply a reason code and addenda record to the entry detail." +
                "<br>Please type 'h' and press the next entry button to open the help screen."+endSpanCss +
                "<br><br><br>"+header1Css+"Reason Codes"+ endSpanCss +
                "<br>"+table+"R01 - Insufficient Funds" +
                "<br>R02 - Account Closed" +
                "<br>R03 - No Account" +
                "<br>R04 - Invalid Account Number" +
                "<br>R05 - Unauthorized Debit to Consumer Account" +
                "<br>R06 - Returned per ODFI Request" +
                "<br>R07 - Auth Revoked by Customer" +
                "<br>R08 - Payment Stopped" +
                "<br>R09 - Uncollected Funds" +
                "<br>R10 - Customer Advises Not Authorized" +
                "<br>R11 - Check Truncation Entry Return" +
                "<br>R12 - Branch Sold to Another DFI" +
                "<br>R13 - Invalid ACH Routing Number" +
                "<br>R14 - Represenative Payee Deceased or Unable to Continue" +
                "<br>R15 - Beneficiary or Account Holder Deceased" +
                "<br>R16 - Account Frozen" +
                "<br>R17 - File Record Edit Criteria" +
                "<br>R18 - Improper Effective Entry Date" +
                "<br>R19 - Account Field Error" +
                "<br>R20 - Non-Transaction Amount" +
                "<br>R21 - Invalid Company Information" +
                "<br>R22 - Invalid Individual ID Number"+endTable;

         //Below code creates the GUI for the return builder portion of the program. 
          Object[] options1 = {"Next Entry","Next Batch","Finished"};//Changes the default buttons. 
          BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();     
          panel.setLayout(border);
          panel.add(new JLabel(text),BorderLayout.NORTH);//Adds the label to the top of the panel.               
          JTextField textField = new JTextField(10); 
          panel.add(textField,BorderLayout.SOUTH);//Adds a user-input text area to the bottom of the panel.

          int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Return Builder", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options1, JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the default option as the final argument to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Return Builder",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
    options1, options1[0]);
```

This will have the side effect of making that button have the initial keyboard focus whenever the dialog is displayed.  If you don't want that, you can force the JTextField to receive the focus whenever it is displayed in a window:

```
textField.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
    @Override
    public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
        final Component c = e.getComponent();
        long flags = e.getChangeFlags();
        if ((flags & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0 &&
                c.isShowing()) {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    c.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

A side note:  For asking the user to select from a list of known options, a [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) is a better choice than a JTextField.  Your Help option can simply be a different JButton, present in the message body of the JOptionPane.

Comment: What if I want to have both the button and the text field selected, so the user could quickly type something and just hit enter? That was my purpose in using the JTextField because it can be extremely fast if the user has 30+ entry details and the ability to just quickly key numbers and hit enter.

Comment: The default option button is always activated by pressing Enter anywhere in the JOptionPane dialog.  Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Note the case with my JOptionsPane. I am not sure if it is because I used objects to replace the button text or because I added a JTextField but the default component became the JTextField. (Which is great, I want that to happen).

The problem is I want the cursor to already be in the JTextField for the user, AND the button to be the default. When I followed the first set of instructions above the button became default but I lost my JTextField cursor. I'm about to try the second method as well and will update.